# Angular2 - Inject active instance of AppComponent into Child Component

Tags: angular, angular2-components

My application child components need to access the active instance of AppComponent for various reasons, so i tried the below to get the AppComponent reference into ChildComponents, it works but its not injecting the active instance of AppComponent instead am getting a new instance of AppComponent in all my childcomponent. So how to resolve this issue.

Posted Source in GIT

https://github.com/jeevaengg21/angular2-parent-inject

**Updated**

```
import { NgModule, Inject, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-page1',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
})
export class ChildComponent1 implements IChild {
...
constructor(private appComponent: AppComponent) {
  console.log('inside ChildComponent1'+appComponent);

}
...
}
```

child.lazy.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';
import { ChildRoutingModule } from './child.lazy.routing';
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';
import { AppModule } from '../app.module';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule,ChildRoutingModule],
  declarations: [ChildComponent]
})
export class ChildModule {}
```

child.lazy.routing.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: ChildComponent },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(appRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class ChildRoutingModule { }
```

app.routing.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/child', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'child', loadChildren: "app/child/child.lazy.module#ChildModule" },
 ];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,

  ],
  providers: [MainService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Solved:**

Upgrade Angular2 and Angular-cli

Comment: Have you tried to remove `AppComponent` from `providers` array?

Comment: @yurzui, am loading my ChildCompoents through module (loadchildren) so if i remove `AppComponent` from `providers` am getting `class ChildComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for AppComponent!`

Comment: try this, export AppComponent from AppModule `exports` array, then import AppModule to `LazyModule`

Comment: or create shared module, then add AppComponent to this share module `exports`, then imports share module in AppModule and LazyModule

Comment: Please check this https://plnkr.co/edit/6CA0pic6tyCTvsd72JVs?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui thanks for your effort, i have followed your plunker and re-alligned my code but still getting `Error in ./ChildComponent class ChildComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for AppComponent!` . even Tried after sever restart

Comment: @yurzui your plunker code work as expected but that implementation in my code is not working

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example on github?

Comment: @yurzui ok i will do

Comment: @TiepPhan ur solution will not work `Uncaught Error: Unexpected directive 'AppComponent' imported by the module 'SharedModule'`

Comment: waiting for your source code on github, after that, i'll looking for your issue

Comment: as a side question why do you want the child to get an instance of AppComponent?

Comment: @yurzui  https://github.com/jeevaengg21/angular2-parent-inject

Comment: @TiepPhan https://github.com/jeevaengg21/angular2-parent-inject

Comment: @OferHerman - in my use case parent need to control all the child loaded dynamically and it will perform some actions, so every dynamic child needs to share its instance state with parent, all also one use case allow childs to update parent component.

Comment: @Jeevanantham for the child -> parent communication why not use `Output` parameters or a common service that serves as a proxy?

Comment: @OferHerman - thanks for ur concern i have used it in required areas, but one particular use case requires the questioned one, am parallel working on that. @yurzui is plnker is `exactly` what i want but that implementation not working for me, it would be useful if you refer my gitlink

Comment: update angular-cli to version beta-26 - it's stable than larger version

Comment: @TiepPhan Thanks will upgrade, you guys saved my day.